# I think This is an Error Code, Cocoa Programming

Tags: cocoa, string, text

I was trying to make an app for practice. Its basically a greeting app written in Cocoa and Objective-C. It has a textfield that asks for the user name. And a textView that prints out Hello, userName. Okay, I got this done with a button that starts the action. When I type in something say Kris. And pressed the button, It came up with something like this

Hello, `<NSTextField:0x100223740>`

Nothin else

I am not sure what the words in the <> mean...

Thanks in Advance,
Kris

Comment: Could you check your question, it seems that you put some text between angle brackets that is not rendered well... You may use the edit tricks on the right to fix it.

Comment: Also, if you want some help on this, we need more info about how you build the UI (did you use Interface Builder, did you proceed to the expected bindings,...) and about your code (where is your controller code, how does it look like).

Answer (score 2):

your not returning the textviews text.

try:

```
NSString *helloUser = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@!",textView.text];
NSLog(@"OUTPUT:  %@",helloUser);
```

Comment: @Kris: … And no, it's not an error code. `%@` logs the description of the object you pass for it; if you had passed a string, the string's description would be the string itself. Most objects describe themselves as `<ClassName pointer>`, where `ClassName` is the class of the object (in this case, NSTextField) and `pointer` is its address in memory. By the way, NSTextField and NSTextView are very different classes—don't call a text field a text view, nor vice versa.